# Google Form: Include hyperlink in Email of the Doc's Google Drive location

Tags: javascript, email, hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using a Google Form to email a completed PDF to the user who submitted the form. The script is also saving a Google Doc copy on Google Drive.  Everything works great except one thing.  I would like to include this hyperlink in the body of the email with the PDF attached. Below are the scripts I am using to save and send the email.....

to save and close the temporary document:

```
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```

to convert temporary document to PDF:

```
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
```

to attach PDF and send the email:

```
var subject = "Name";
var body = "Attached is the Auto-Generated PDF;
MailApp.sendEmail(user_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
```

Answer (score 0):

A hyperlink in HTML is an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

To incorporate the URL into the document, you'll need to use a JavaScript text formula.  You can concatenate text with the plus sign.

```
"<a href='" + urlToDoc + "'>Stack Overflow</a>"
```

You need to somehow get the URL of the new Doc, and put that URL into a variable.

```
var fileNewDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
var urlToDoc = fileNewDoc.getUrl();
```

[Google Documentation - File Class - getUrl() Method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl())

So the code would be something like this:

```
var fileNewDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
var urlToDoc = fileNewDoc.getUrl();

var pdf = fileNewDoc.getAs("application/pdf");

var body = "Attached is the Auto-Generated PDF. <br><br>";
body = body + "<a href='" + urlToDoc + "'>Your Link to the Copy</a>";
```